# Error importing CSV file with data in mm:ss.0 format when used timestamp without timezone

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, pgadmin, csv-import

Received a CSV file which I am trying to import into PostgreSQL. One column called "created_date" has a mm:ss.0 format when viewed in Excel. I was asked to import this column with a "timestamp without timezone" datatype. But on doing so get the below error msg. I'm using SQL on pgAdmin to import data into PostgreSQL. How can I fix this?

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "05:43.0" CONTEXT: 
>   COPY transactions, line 2, column created_date: "05:43.0" SQL state:
>   22007

Opened the CSV file in notepad. Sample lines below

```
SERIAL_NUM_TRANS,CURR,AMT,STATE,DATE,MERCH_CAT,MERCH_CTRY,ENTRY_METHOD,USER_ID,TYP,SRC,ID

0,GBP,3731,COMP,05:43.0,bar,AUS,ged,7285c1ec-31d0-4022-b311-0ad9227ef7f4,CARD,HEW,2j3hv5666km7

1,GBP,583,COMP,08:39.1,,CA,ged,20100a1d-12bc-41ed-a5e1-bc46216e9696,CARD,NEP,kaskdkjr878638i
```

Sample of lines of data

Comment: A `created_date` without a date doesn't sound very useful.  My guess is that in Excel you are only seeing part of the value and things are getting messed up in transferring the data to Postgres.

Comment: Open the csv file with a text editor program, and please [edit] your question to show us a few lines. To @GordonLinoff’s point, Excel can do strange things to date time columns.

Comment: Thanks @O.Jones for the advice, put in some lines from the data.

Comment: Your edit is helpful. Some questions (from you to whomever gave you this file and your instructions).  What is the meaning of `08:39.1`? Does it mean `08:39:06` (with the `.1` meaning a tenth of an hour), or what? Do you really want to import this into a `timestamp without time zone` column? It's better suited to `time without time zone`; it lacks any date.

Comment: Ideally one must load the contents of the csv into a temporary table with all columns having  `text` datatype and then convert the columns to appropriate datatypes to suit the main, target table's types through an `insert into select `

Comment: @O.Jones I did notice that once i moved the csv data into an excel - this 05:43.0 showed up as 10/11/2015  9:05:43 AM.

Comment: @KaushikNayak do you mean create a table with text datatype columns and upload the csv data into it and then move the table with the data into a new table with the target datatypes?

Comment: Yes and in fact  that also gives you a better control to handle bad data.

Comment: @KaushikNayak I tried doing that and see this -- ERROR:  column "serial_num_users" is of type integer but expression is of type text
LINE 14: select serial_num_users, 
                ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
SQL state: 42804
Character: 184

Comment: @KaushikNayak  some lines from the query I used                                                                                     
CREATE TABLE DB.users (serial_num_users text, created_date text )                                                 CREATE TABLE DB.users_final( serial_num_users int, created_date date)                                                                                           insert into DB.users_final( serial_num_users, created_date)                                
select serial_num_users, created_date from DB.users

Comment: For `serial_num_users`,  you may cast it to `INTEGER`  witth an expression `serial_num_users::int`. I'm not sure why you want  a value `05:43.0` to correspond to a `date` datatype. It looks like a time` to me.

Comment: @KaushikNayak you are right. Meant to type timestamp.

Comment: A `timestamp` is different from `time` datatype. If you want to store it as a timestamp, where do you get the date component from?